# Why am I getting incorrect time using tm time?

Tags: c++, time, time.h

I am subtracting the current time with one minute earlier, however C++ is saying the difference is 18000 seconds, which is like 300 minutes (4 hours). Really confused as to why this is happening. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream> 

int main(){
    time_t timer; 
    struct tm t = {0}; 
    double seconds; 
    
    t.tm_year = 122; //2022
    t.tm_mon = 7 //august
    t.tm_mday = 29; //29
    t.tm_hour = 21; //10pm
    t.tm_min = 35; //35
    t.tm_sec = 0; 

    time(&timer); //get current time
    seconds = difftime(timer, mktime(&t)); 

    std::cout << seconds; 
}
```

Comment: Are you running this in an on-line compiler? If so, what time zone is the server in vs. your time zone?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the fact that in your `t` struct, both `tm_isdst` and `tm_gmtoff` are default-set to `0`, rather than (whatever is appropriate to your local time zone).  I suggest initializing your struct with `time_t x = time(NULL); t = *localtime(&x);` before setting the various `tm_*` fields, and see if that gives you a better result.

Answer (score 1):

The `time` function in the C library deals with UTC time while `mktime` assumes your local time. This is explicit in the documentation.

> time() returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (**UTC**).

> The mktime() function converts a broken-down time structure, **expressed as local time**, to calendar time representation.

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream> 

int main(){
    struct tm t; 
    memset(&t,0,sizeof(tm));
    t.tm_year = 2022 - 1900;
    t.tm_mon = 8 - 1;  
    t.tm_mday = 29; 
    t.tm_hour = 23;
    t.tm_min = 28; 
    t.tm_sec = 0;
    t.tm_isdst = 1;
    
    time_t mktm = mktime(&t);
    time_t timer = time(0);

    double seconds = difftime(timer,mktm); 
    std::cout << seconds << std::endl;
    std::cout << mktm << std::endl;
    std::cout << timer << std::endl;

    struct tm local;
    localtime_r( &mktm, &local );
    std::cout << "gmtoff:" << local.tm_gmtoff << std::endl;
}
```

Observe that I passed `t.tm_isdst=1` because I am in Chicago which is currently on daylight and I get this:

```
$ g++ /tmp/test2.cpp -o ./test2
$ ./test2
30
1661833680
1661833710
gmtoff:-18000
```

So this is telling me that the time structure is just 30 seconds before the current time, which is your intended result.
I also requested to print the localtime gmt offset which is minus 18,000 seconds (-5 hours), which seems correct.

Note that the timestamps `1661833680` and `1661833710` are both in GMT as you can check on epochconverter.com

[image]

Now when I run this exact code on [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bGTsEsdKf) I get a different result:

```
18031
1661816160
1661834191
gmtoff:0
```

So it is telling me now that the difference is now 5 hours. This is because it assumed that the time I was passing was in London time! But now it is 4:41am in London.

Notice that the gmtoffset is now zero indicating that this machine is in London (or set its timezone as UK).

So what I believe it is happening in your case is that you are somewhere in UTC-4 (New York?) and logged on a computer in the UK or using compiler explorer as myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am having windows using bash.exe

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/tzutil.exe /s "Central America Standard Time"
$ date "+%a %d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %Z"
Tue 30-Aug-2022 01:10:01 CDT
$ /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/tzutil.exe /g
Central America Standard Time
$ /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/tzutil.exe /s "E. South America Standard Time"
$ date "+%a %d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %Z"
Tue 30-Aug-2022 01:10:48 CDT
$ ./a.out
Seconds: 6191
mktm   : 1661833680
timer  : 1661839871
gmtoff : -18000
$ tzutil /s "India Standard Time"
$ ./a.out
Seconds: 47632
mktm   : 1661792280
timer  : 1661839912
gmtoff : 19800
```

Hence the output of a.out varies based on system timings like the way of two planets from two galaxies having same timing using TZ environment variable (at Linux oriented OS).
I have set my system back to IST using admin privileges again.

```
C:> C:\Windows\System32\tzutil.exe /g
India Standard Time
```

Same thing applicable at browser inside system/mobile/external applications like ATM/... when web server/any application at a system using different TZ/tzutil location changes.